# Getting file from azure storage and sending it via Post method throw error but works with local files

Tags: javascript, node.js, blob, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have made a request to server via post method.

It's working when file is on local

Here's the request working

```
var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'url':'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/xxxxx/imports?datasetDisplayName=test',
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${tokenResponse.accessToken} `
    },
    formData: {
        '': {
            'value': fs.createReadStream('/Users/userName/Downloads/file.pbix'),
            'options': {
                'filename': 'file.pbix',
                'contentType': null
            }
        }
    }
};
request(options, function (error, response) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    console.log(response.body);
});
```

Now I would change it to get file from Azure storage

```
const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient('tenants');
const baseUrl = containerClient.url
const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient('file/Url/On/AzureBlob')
let blobData
try {
    blobData = await blobClient.download(0)
    console.log(blobData)

} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}

var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'url':'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/xxxxx/imports?datasetDisplayName=test',
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${tokenResponse.accessToken} `
    },
    formData: {
        '': {
            'value': fs.createReadStream('blobData.blobDownloadStream'),
            'options': {
                'filename': 'file.pbix',
                'contentType': null
            }
        }
    }
};
request(options, function (error, response) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    console.log(response.body);
});
```

Here I get an error message from the server ( MS Server )

```
'{"error":{"code":"UnknownError","pbi.error":{"code":"UnknownError","parameters":{},"details":[],"exceptionCulprit":1}}}'
```

I guess that the error came from the way I download file and sent it to the server.

Is there a way to get the same file type/format as `fs.createReadStream` for AzureBlobClient ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify a file path for [fs.createReadStream(some path)](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options), but in your second scenario, you provided a string that not a valid file path.

So basically,if you want to use `fs.createReadStream` in your code, you should download the file to local as a temp file and then upload it. Try code below :

```
const fileName = "blob Name"
const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient('tenants')
const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(fileName)
const tempFilePath = "/some local temp path/" + fileName

blobClient.downloadToFile(tempFilePath).then(function(){
    console.log("file downloaded")
    var options = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'url':'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/xxxxx/imports?datasetDisplayName=test',
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${tokenResponse.accessToken} `
        },
        formData: {
            '': {
                'value': fs.createReadStream(tempFilePath),
                'options': {
                    'filename': 'file.pbix',
                    'contentType': null
                }
            }
        }
    };
    request(options, function (error, response) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
        console.log(response.body);
    });

    //remove temp file after upload
    fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath)
})
```